# Rules for Intercepting Attacks

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

Is there any charms/actions that allow you to intercept an attack meant for someone else?

I'm playing a Solar (Exclipse Caste) character who has an Oath flaw that I will not attack anyone who hasn't first attacked me. As such I'm looking for loopholes that would allow me to intercept attacks/force someone to attack my character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For Starters, Use the *Defend Other* Action

Scroll of Errata (2012 version, one also known as the 2½ edition) introduces the Defend Other action. It doesn't *force* an attack to hit your PC, but does tempt enemies into using the opportunity if they score enough successes.

## Forbidden Writings: Scroll of the Monk

Page 43, **Falling Blossom Style**, *Living Shield Technique* can outright interpose the stylist in the way of an attack, 'forcefully' taking it (or Parrying it). This is a first Charm in the style chain, so should be comparably easy to get.

Page 146, **Scarlet Patterned Battlefield Style**, *Fallen Ivory Defense*. More esoteric and high-prerequisite than the above, but worth acquainting yourself with.

Page 135, **Prismatic Arrangement of Creation Style**, *Charm Redirection Technique*. In case you ever get to bend the rules so much you get a Sidereal style, there's this. But it's highly unlikely that you'll be able to obtain this technique.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Vicky_Molokh's answer;

**Heavenly Guardian Defence** (Exalted p.193) perfectly parries "any attack" and where most charms specify they only work on attacks directed at the Solar, this one does not.

Since you are playing an Eclipse caste you can learn charms of other exalts, Lunars have several charms that interact with the Defend-Other action that may interest you:

**Mother Grizzly Attitude** (Errata P.54), This is exactly what you are looking for, *"While the Lunar is protecting a character with a Defend Other action, he may use this Charm to prevent any attackers from targeting the warded character even if they overcome the Lunar’s interposed DV with their attack roll, forcing them to instead direct their attacks against the Lunar for the duration."* 1st charm off of a Stamina Excellency.

**Ferocious Guardian Beast Stance** (Glories: Luna p.23) a perfect defence that can only be used on the behalf of someone you are defending. 2rd charm off a Dexterity Excellency.

**Lunar Hero Style** (Lunars p.194) has some charms deep in the tree (5th Charm) that may interest you as well, particularly *Den Mother Method* and *Running Through the Herd*.